# How do you iterate/get ever role ID from a user?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to iterate through the entire list of role IDs from a single user and see if that user has one of the role IDs on a file I have. Right at "AccessListR.includes()" is where I don't know what to put because that's where the list of user role IDs should go or something like that. I think I need a function to iterate through them and return them each time to the if statement.
Except...
I don't know how to access the list of roles from a user.
Here's my code:

```
if ((AccessListBot.includes(message.author.username) || AccessListBotR.includes()) && message.content.includes(prefix)){
message.channel.send("ERROR: You have been blacklisted from using this bot.")
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Collection.some()` to check if one of the role returns true:

```js
if ((AccessListBot.includes(message.author.username) || (message.member.roles.cache.some((role) => AccessListBotR.includes(role.id))) && message.content.includes(prefix)){
message.channel.send("ERROR: You have been blacklisted from using this bot.")
}
```